# Term and theories about "relation-free" elements in a group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

For a group $G$, there are two elements a, b which are "relation-free",
i.e., there is no nonempty, reduced word $W(X,Y)$ such that $W(a,b)=1$ in $G$.

Is there any terminologies or theories for that?

(My group is a free product of finite cyclic groups, and I'm considering one element is not contained in a factor, but is a product of generators of each factors.)

Comment: In other words, $\langle a,b \rangle$ is a free subgroup with $\{a,b\}$ as a basis, no?

Comment: In addition to the comment of @AGenevois, as your setting is in the subgroups of a free product of finite cyclic groups you may be interested in the [Kurosh subgroup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurosh_subgroup_theorem).

Comment: I'm calling this a "free pair", and more generally $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ a free $n$-tuple if the corresponding map $F_n\to G$ is injective.

Comment: @AGenevois;@Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda Yes, it is. Maybe, I should ask more, I want to know some about a normally generated subgroup with the two elements. For instance, $\langle X^n, Y\rangle \subsetneq \langle X,Y\rangle$ for any $n>1$, but I don't know whether $\langle\langle X^n, Y\rangle\rangle_G \subsetneq \langle\langle X,Y \rangle\rangle_G$.

Comment: Understanding normal closures may be quite difficult. But for free products of finite groups, powerful tools are available. What is your question precisely?

Comment: @AGenevois What is the powerful tools for normal closures in a free product of finite groups? Precisely, I want to know whether $\langle\langle X^n, Y \rangle\rangle_G \neq \langle\langle X, Y \rangle\rangle_G$ for $G$ the free product of 4 finite cyclic groups. Here, $X$ can be considered as a product of generators of each factor, and $X$ and $Y$ are "relation-free" (i.e. $\langle X,Y \rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Usual tools are: normal form, Bass-Serre tree, small cancellation. From small cancellation, a positive answer to your question can be proved if the maximal length of a common subword in (conjugates of) $X$ and $Y$ is sufficiently *small* compared to the lengths of $X$ and $Y$. In full generality, I don't know. But it should be true that there exists some $N$ such that $\langle \langle X^n,Y^m \rangle \rangle = \langle \langle X^p,Y^q\rangle \rangle$ iff $(n,m)=(p,q)$ for all $n,m,p,q \geq N$.

Comment: @AGenevois Thank you. I tried using normal form, but I don't know how for the normal closure. I wonder the case that you gave a positive answer. Isn't it depend on the relators of G (not only the word corresponding to $X$ and $Y$)? Can it be independent with G? Also, on your last statement.

Comment: What you are asking in the comments is essentially unrelated to the question. You could ask a new one. I will say there is probably subtlty in what you are asking. For example, it is non trivial to show that $G$ isn't normally generated by a single element.

Comment: @qkqh: Yes, the argument is essentially independent of the finite groups used to defined $G$. One way to justify this could be to say that small cancellation only deals with loxodromic isometries in the Bass-Serre tree while finite groups are elliptic. So there is no interaction between the two.

Comment: As @AGenevois says, small-cancellation techniques can probably be used to show that $\langle\langle X^n,Y\rangle\rangle\neq \langle\langle X,Y\rangle\rangle$ for all *sufficiently large* $n$. For smaller $n$ (i.e. $n>1$), this is likely to be closer to the theory of one-relator groups with torsion.  I'd recommend checking out the papers of Jim Howie, who has done a lot of work on one-relator quotients of free products, IIRC.

Comment: @HJRW Sorry, but I could not find theorems to obtain it (for sufficiently large n). Could you tell me what I refer to more specifically?

Comment: @qkqh: there’s a vast literature on small-cancellation techniques, and you will need to learn some of it. Perhaps you should start by looking at Denis Osin’s paper on combinatorial Dehn filling.